# Javascript convert string date to a valid date

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a date value inside a string with value: **Sun May 16 2021 09:54:25 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília).**

I have to convert this date to a valid date, but I'm getting this error: **TypeError: date.getDate is not a function**

code:

```
Date.parse(stringData);
```

Comment: did you try `new Date(your_string)` ?

Comment: Running this in a console works fine: `Date.parse('Sun May 16 2021 09:54:25 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília');`. The code you're showing us doesn't seem related to the question. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) especially a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Valid date, as in do you want it be in a specific format e.g. dd/mm/yyyy etc?

Comment: @AndriiLukianenko It worked! OMG I was doing some bad stuffs here, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just do it new Date(your_string);

Thanks Andrii Lukianenko!

Answer (score 0):

Date parse return int. First create Date and then run getDate

[image]